# Replace string inside another string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below string

```
Hello this is username (xxx) welcome to the portal
```

I need to match and replace "username (xxx)" with a string encapsulated with html tag. So it will look like the following.

```
Hello this is <b>username (xxx) </b> welcome to the portal
```

Note that (xxx) is a dynamic variable.

How do i do it using regex expression and javascript?

Comment: Google "javascript string regex replace".

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Couple sample inputs and outputs could help.

Comment: Try this http://regex101.com/r/wC3tP7/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fj7fmooy/

```
    var str = 'Hello this is username (xxx) welcome to the portal'
    str = str.replace(/username \((.+)\)/, "<b> username ($1) </b>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this:

### [Demo](http://regexr.com/39f03)

```
var string = "Hello this is username (xxx) welcome to the portal"

var newString = string.replace(/([a-z]+\s\(.+\))/g, '<b>username (xxx)</b>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture all the characters from the string  `username` upto the next `)` symbol.

```
> "Hello this is username (xxx) welcome to the portal".replace(/(username[^\)]*\))/g, "<b>$1 </b>")
'Hello this is <b>username (xxx) </b> welcome to the portal'
```